# How can I insert text at the end of a group of lines?

Tags: insert-mode, visual-block

Let's say I had a block of text...

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum dolor
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

...and I wanted to insert a `.` at the end of each line. What would the best approach be to achieve this?

Answer (score 65):

I do the following to append text to multiple lines:

- `<c-V>` - Enter Visual Block mode.
- Use `j`/`k` to select the lines.
- `$` - Move cursor to last character.
- `A` - Enter insert mode after last character.
- Insert desired text.
- `<Esc>` - Exit insert mode and finish block append.

When compared to writing `:norm` after selection there are even less key presses, but the real reason why I use this is because it's more instinctive for me to work on Visual Block mode for this type of changes.

Comment: Very useful combined with [pasting a column of text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120598/2641825).

Comment: <c-v> is ctrl + v guys...if anyone is as dumb as me

Answer (score 18):

On first line just type:
 `4:norm A.`

`4` and `:` create a range for you and then `norm A.` adds the dot to each line

Another solution for longer paragraphs could be:
`Vip<C-v>$A.<Esc>`

The first step is to select the paragraph with `Vip` then you change to visual block mode and move the cursor to the end of each line with `$` then you add the `.` to each line with `A.` and got to normal mode with `<Esc>` to see the change be applied to each line.

Comment: What is this `:A` command? I did not find it via `:h :A`

Comment: my bad. In fact didn't test the answer. I'm updating it. It should use the normal command just like @Kritixi Lhitos answer

Comment: Two characters less than `4:norm A.` would be `4:s/$/.`

Answer (score 7):

First you can visually select them using `V` and then use the movement keys to select the entire text (or if the text were strictly a paragraph you could do [starting at the first line] `V}`). And then type `:`. This should bring up something like `:'<,'>` in the command-line.

```
:'<'>normal A.
```

This executes `normal A.` on the selected lines. `normal A.` executes `A.` as normal mode keystrokes. This `A`ppends a `.` at the end of each of the selected lines.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add dot at the end of all lines:

```
:%norm A.
```

or you can use search and replace:

```
:%s/$/./
```

% is whole file, $ is end of line

Comment: Since @vim.ryan asked for a block of text instead of the whole file,  `:1,4s/$/./`   which substitutes last character with a dot on lines one through four inclusive.

Answer (score 4):

To make it a little more general, you can record a macro on a single line, and then play it back on each line in your visually selected range.

Record a macro into a register (the q register in this example):

```
qqA.<Esc>q
```

You can then visually select the lines you want to operate on:

```
Vip
```

And then play back your macro on each line (the range will be auto-filled):

```
:'<,'>norm @q
```